# W3c validation error while using sass arithmetic operator

Tags: css, sass, w3c-validation

I'm trying to validate my website using w3c validator, i have the following sass code.

```
$paddingXL: 140px;
.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1360px + #{$paddingXL * 2} + 40px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

which is compiled into the following css code

```
.Wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1360px + 280px + 40px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto
}
```

The above code throws the following validation error on w3c

```
Error: CSS: Parse Error.

 + 280px + 40px;margin-left:au
```

and the validator is highlighting ";" after "40px", can someone please help me to pass the w3c validation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`max-width: 1360px + 280px + 40px;` is not valid css. You can calculate the width in sass: `max-width: 1360px + $paddingXL * 2 + 40px;`. Just remove `#{}`.

Answer (score 0):

If you surround the expression in calc you'll get the desired value:

```
$paddingXL: 140px;
.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: calc(1360px + #{$paddingXL * 2} + 40px);
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: Why use calc() for simple addition with all the same unit?

Comment: You're right, that is a much better solution. Also happens to be part of the chosen answer :)